# Braintree Server Side Code Help For Newbies

Tags: ruby, heroku, braintree

I am building an iOS app in Swift for selling products and am working to integrate Braintree to accept payment. I have been following the documentation given by Braintree but I have hit a roadblock at setting up a server to process the transaction as shown here https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-server/ruby

I am rather new to programming so the documentation is not detailed enough in assisting me in the setup of my own server, i.e.: I have no clue where to type 'gem braintree' nor where the files are going, neither what a successful transaction looks like. I have no clue whether to install this server side code on the app or on my computer etc. I wish to also deploy this server to a service like Heroku rather than hosting it on my computer. I have been digging n testing everything I could get my hands on for the past 4 days so I'm really desperate for help here.

Comment: If you want a quickstart: create a `my_app_name.rb` which contains `require sinatra`. Then enter the code from the Braintree tutorial in that file. Run it with `ruby my_app_name.rb` and the server will run locally. Follow [the Rack instructions from heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rack) to deploy. But keep in mind you may need to alter this code to be production-ready, especially considering security in payments is important. You could probably find a SaaS solution for payments if you are really going for a plug-and-play approach.

Answer (score 0):

I have integrated BrainTree using .Net SDK/JS.

In Developer point of view, first we have to create a sandbox account with BrainTree. There we will get the below important key's.

1. Merchant Account ID
2. Public Key
3. Private Key

These 3 values act as your credentials for your integration. In order to create a transaction we have to create the below thing with BrainTree.

Need to create Submerchant Account:

1. Sub-merchant ID(this submerchant ID is different from Merchant Account ID)

   - We will get this submerchant id, when we create an account using bank account number, routing number, SSN and required fields as per documentation.

This submerchant account ID will holds the information to whom the transaction to be made.

Finally, coming to transaction part - BrainTree will provide a form which holds the inputs for CC details. To achieve this we have to use the appropriate front end code(design page code, as provided in the documentation). This code will refers the BrainTree dll. After configuring this code successfully, our application will refers the BrainTree dll and we will get their own form in our application with textboxes provided for CC details.

Once we submit the form with all inputs entered correctly, **Nonce** value would get generated in the hidden filed 'paymentmethod_nonce'. Now using this Nonce value, Submerchant ID, Amount value and the 3 Keys(mentioned above) we can create a transaction.

We have different types of transactions like Vault, Authorize, SubmitForSettlement, these all varies based on our requirement.

Once a transaction has made, you can see all the details in their BrainTree console.